# Filing to expand on already filed utility patent, how do I go about this?

Tags: process, continuation

I have already filed non-provisional utility patent applications. I need to add more information prior to the USPTO publishing one of them. Basically, I'm going to copy the existing application, and add a good bit of specification and drawings. I'm doing this because I've found new uses for and created better explanations of my inventions.
1. Do I file just a provisional, or a regular utility application?
2. Do I file some form with said application, noting that it is an addition to or expansion of existing applications?
3. Do I file the expanded version with some kind of phrasing such as, "This application is an addendum/expansion/addition to patent application #XXXXXX"?
4. Or is further filing simply treated by the USPTO a whole entire different application?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "addendum" to a patent application. You have a couple of options. One is to file a provisional and later file a non-provisional that could be a CIP (Continuation in Part) to the current application, also getting priority from the non-provisional, or could just be a new non-provisional.

Comment: Might be nice to define "CIP" for those who don't know what it stands for.